# How can I draw on a sublayer of a UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to draw some fancy graphics on a UIButton using CoreGraphics and CALayers, but I can't get anything on a sublayer to display.

Here's how I set up my sublayer:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        CALayer *buttonLayer = self.layer;
        buttonLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
        buttonLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        self.myDelegate =  [[PlayerButtonLayerDelegate alloc] init];

        CALayer *customDrawn = [CALayer layer];
        customDrawn.delegate = self.myDelegate;
        customDrawn.frame = buttonLayer.frame;
        customDrawn.masksToBounds = YES;
        [buttonLayer insertSublayer:customDrawn atIndex:0];
        [customDrawn setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    return self;
}
```

PlayerButtonLayerDelegate just implements `drawLayer: inContext:` like this:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    CGRect rectangleFrame = layer.bounds;
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = 
        [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: rectangleFrame];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [rectanglePath fill];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

The code gets called (I can set a breakpoint or output to NSLog), but nothing gets displayed: I just have a transparent button (as indicated by the main layer), with and without any button text.

What do I have to change to "draw" on the sublayer?

Comment: You should set the `frame` of your sublayer to the `bounds` of the button layer, not its frame. Not sure if that's the only problem though.

Comment: Doh .. :-) Can you submit this as an answer so I can +1/accept it? Obvious once someone points it out! Please let me know if there are other problems! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 [customDrawn setFrame:buttonLayer.bounds];
```